# Redefine verbatim environment

Tags: macros, environments, verbatim, pandoc

I have a text with source code, which I would like to display. I am using pandoc, so I have to use either verbatim or listings environment. Unfortunately, I can't use listings package (due to Cyrillic symbols issue). So, I stuck with verbatim only. But verbatim is unable to make word wrap. I found spverbatim package which is suited to my needs, and now I would like to redefine verbatim enviroment.

1) At first, I've tried to redefine it with let command:

```
\let\verbatim\spverbatim
```

But it just doesn't compile, with no errors. Looked like the whole compiling process was hanged up.

2) Then, I've tried to use renewenvironment command:

```
\renewenvironment{verbatim}{\begin{spverbatim}}{%
   \end{spverbatim}\ignorespacesafteren
}
```

and got an error: 
"! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=80000].
\reserved@a ...tim}\edef \@currenvline {\on@line }
\csuse {@begin@spverbatim@...
l.372 \begin{verbatim}"

Is there any way to redefine build in environments like verbatim or I am doing something totally wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the same idea as `spverbatim`; I also added `\raggedright` or several overfull boxes would be expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@xobeysp{\mbox{}\space}
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily\raggedright}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Something which will break but is otherwise typeset @#verbatim#} with special characters accessible
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you plan to use `verbatim` in lists, a small change is needed (thanks to Christof R for noting):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@xobeysp{\mbox{}\space}
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily\raggedright\leftskip\@totalleftmargin}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Something which will break but is otherwise typeset @#verbatim#} with special characters accessible
\end{verbatim}

\begin{itemize}
\item Text
\begin{verbatim}
Something which will break but is otherwise typeset @#verbatim#} with special characters accessible
\end{verbatim}

\begin{itemize}
\item Text
\begin{verbatim}
Something which will break but is otherwise typeset @#verbatim#} with special characters accessible
\end{verbatim}
\end{itemize}

\item Text
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\raggedright` corrupts the correct placement when using a `verbatim` environment within a list.