# New environment based on two existing environments (mdframed, spverbatim)

Tags: environments, verbatim, mdframed

I would like to define an environment that puts verbatim text using the `spverbatim` package into a frame defined by the `mdframed` package. Here's my (naive) approach:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{240,248,255}

\newmdenv
[
backgroundcolor=lightblue,
hidealllines=true,
frametitlerule=false,
frametitle=,
]{notesx}

\newenvironment{notes}
{\begin{notesx}\begin{spverbatim}}
{\end{spverbatim}\end{notesx}}

\begin{document}

% works
\begin{notesx}
\begin{spverbatim}
Test 1
Test 2
\end{spverbatim}
\end{notesx}

% does not work
\begin{notes}
Test 1
Test 2
\end{notes}


\end{document}
```

When using the defined environment `notes` I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
\end{document}
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
```

Using the environment `notesx` with added `spverbatim` environment works fine.

EDIT:
Using `surroundwithmdframed` works but when setting this for a custom defined environment `\newenvironment{notes}{\begin{spverbatim}}{\end{spverbatim}}` instead of `spverbatim` to have a nicer name it does not work: `! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `spverbatim` is like `verbatim` and wants to “see” the *string* `\end{spverbatim}` for being able to end.

Comment: Using `surroundwithmdframed` works but when setting this for a custom defined environment `\newenvironment{notes}{\begin{spverbatim}}{\end{spverbatim}}` instead of `spverbatim` to have a nicer name it does not work: `! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.`
@egreg
What would be a possible solution for this issue?

Comment: @problemzebra You should update your question with this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same idea as `spverbatim` as I did in [Redefine verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185667/redefine-verbatim-environment)

With the `verbatim` package you can define a new environment to which apply `\surroundwithmdframed`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim,mdframed,ragged2e}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{240,248,255}

\surroundwithmdframed[
  backgroundcolor=lightblue,
  hidealllines=true,
  frametitlerule=false,
  frametitle=,
]{notes}

\makeatletter
\def\notes{\def\@xobeysp{\mbox{}\space}\emergencystretch=\textwidth\RaggedRight\verbatim}
\let\endnotes\endverbatim
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{notes}
Something breakable but otherwise typeset @#verbatim#} with special characters accessible
Test 1
Test 2
\end{notes}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your proposed solution works (the compiled PDF looks fine) but `pdflatex` shows the following error message: `! Undefined control sequence. \notes ...ergencystretch =\textwidth \RaggedRight `

Comment: @problemzebra Sorry, I forgot to load `ragged2e`