# change font of verbatim environment, but not of \verb

Tags: environments, verbatim

I use both `\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}` and `\verb.something.` in my document. I would like the contents of `\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}` to be displayed in a smaller font. I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171866/39366), which is kind of what I want.
In that answer, the verbatim font can be customized via this command:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\verbatimfont}[1]{\renewcommand{\verbatim@font}{\ttfamily#1}}
\makeatother
```

But I would prefer this to be applied to every verbatim environment automatically.

Then I tried to transfer [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185671/39366) answer to my problem, but this also makes the contents of `\verb.someting.` small, which is not what I want.

I also tried defining a custom verbatim environment like this:

```
\newenvironment{smallverbatim}{
\verbatimfont{\footnotesize}\noindent\ignorespaces\begin{verbatim}}%
{\par\noindent%
\ignorespacesafterend\end{verbatim}}
```

But this gave me:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{smallverbatim} on input line 526 ended by \end{itemize}.
```

Is there a way to do what I want to do?

What I need is some kind of macro that replaces every `\begin{verbatim}` with `\verbatimfont{\footnotesize}\begin{verbatim}`, so it shouldn't be impossible, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: The `\verbatimfont`command sets the font for all subsequent `verbratim` environments. So simply putting it in the preamble will do what you want.

Comment: But that also affects the contents of `\verb.foo.` which is not what I want...

Comment: Oops, sorry. But I found an answer.

Comment: Not sure the duplicate is really a duplicate, because the answers there change `\verb.foo.` too, as far as I can see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeXs `verbatim` environment can not be used in `\newenvironment`, because it looks for `\end{verbatim}` in the source.

But there are many packages with improved verbatim capabilities. One of them (`verbatim`) is used here. Among others, it enables you to define your own verbatim environments.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newenvironment{smallverbatim}%
{\small\verbatim}%
{\endverbatim}

\begin{document}

Test: \verb|something| \lipsum*[3]
\begin{smallverbatim}
1   double x, y;
2   double z, w;
3   main();
4   return 0;
\end{smallverbatim}
Test: \verb|something| \lipsum[3]

\begin{smallverbatim}
1   double x, y;
2   double z, w;
3   main();
4   return 0;
\end{smallverbatim}
Test: \verb|something| \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```